# error CS0117: 'EditorSceneManager' does not contain a definition for 'IsGameObjectInScene'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

an error shows i cant make the build in unity 2018.3.8

i try to copy all assets to another folder but still error show

i am really stuck to resolve it

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.postprocessing@2.0.3-preview\PostProcessing\Runtime\PostProcessManager.cs(424,66): error CS0117: 'EditorSceneManager' does not contain a definition for 'IsGameObjectInScene'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Multiple people already had that issue. It seems that it points to an outdated file from PostProcssing version `2.0.3` E.g. in [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/postprocessmanager-error-with-editorscenemanager.673645/) they solved it by

> To fix this, you can delete `Library/PackageCache/` the post processing folder

or

> updating the "Post Processing" package to the verified version in the package manager fixed it.

Currently it should be version `2.1.7`

[image]

and since the entry already exists in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PackagesList.html) (the https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@latest/index.html points to https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.2 which currently still is a dead link) it seems that soon there might come out a version `2.2`

---

In general errors regarding the `Library` folder often are caused by updating the project to a newer Unity version. In most cases those are simply solved by closing Unity, delete the entire `Library` folder and re-open the project in Unity. The `Library` folder is one of the folders Unity completely [generates dynamically](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BehindtheScenes.html) and therefore can be removed without any concerns as also mentioned [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html)

Comment: Thanks it works fine for me.
i just deleted the folder in Library\PackageCache\com.unity.postprocessing and works fine for me.
Thanks Again

Comment: Man, this error is very annoying. Deleting the folder multiple times didn't work for me. Fixed it by updating the very well hidden PostProcessing package. Currently, the version is 2.3.0.